# Prove g is bounded and holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be a holomorphic and univalent function on $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $a\in D$ be a constant.Define function $\displaystyle{g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)-f(a)}-\frac{1}{f'(a)(z-a)}}$ then prove that

1.$g$ is bounded and holomorphic on $D$

2.If $D=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\}$ then $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, multiply the function by $z-a$, and show that what you get is holomorphic with a zero at $a$. Write out the form of the power series at $a$. Then dividing by $z-a$ gives you the power series for the original equation.